# rsync's --link-dest option does not link because of file time

Tags: rsync, timestamps, hard-link

Consider this test case:

```
mkdir a
echo 'blah' > a/test
mkdir b
echo 'blah' > b/test

rsync -r --link-dest=/tmp/b /tmp/a/ /tmp/c
```

As expected, rsync creates `c/test` a hardlink of `b/test` (note the refcount of `2`):

```
# ls -l c/test
-rw-r--r-- 2 root root 16 Jan  6 19:43 test
```

Now see this:

```
rm -r c # start over
touch b/test
rsync -r --link-dest=/tmp/b /tmp/a/ /tmp/c
```

The hardlink is not created:

```
# ls -l c/test
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 16 Jan  6 19:50 test
```

The [manpages](https://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) says (emphasis mine):

> The files must be identical in all **preserved** attributes (e.g.
>   permissions, possibly ownership) in order for the files to be linked
>   together.

However, I think that by default the filetime is not *preserved* and should therefore make no difference here.

What is happening? Is this a bug? What can I do?

My goal is to save space on a continuous integration server that hosts many branches of a repository by hard-linking all the identical files. So my actual command is:
`rsync -r --link-dest=/ci/master /ci-runner/build/ /ci/branch-123`.
This means I don't care about the times, so I thought about `touch`ing them all to the current time before the `rsync` but it would be a somehow crude solution and also touch does not seem to work recursively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the results of rsync's "quick check" algorithm which decides to transfer files based on their size and their timestamp.  As detailed in `man rsync`:

> Rsync  finds  files  that  need to be transferred using a "quick
>   check" algorithm (by default) that looks for files that have changed
>   in size or in last-modified time.  Any changes in the other  preserved  attributes  (as  requested  by  options) are made on the
>   destination file directly when the    quick check indicates that the
>   file’s data does not need to be updated.

You have choices:

- If you want timestamp to be ignored and transfer files based just on changed size, you can use the `--size-only` option.

  Note that this means that `rsync` will not transfer a changed file if the change just so happened to leave the file with the same size.
- If you want `rsync` instead to check if the files' contents are actually identical, use `--checksum`.  This may cause a substantial slow-down.

The "quick check" algorithm is the default because it is a generally good compromise between speed and accuracy.

Comment: At first I didn't see the connection, but yes, makes sense and solves the problem. :)